# How to manually import entries into Craft CMS?

Tags: entries, import, export

I have some entries saved in a JSON file with the standard format that is created with export functionality (expanded). How can I import the entries from this JSON file back to my CMS?

Feed Me seems to be a complex streamline solution, but all I need is a single-time import.
Craftimport only allows XML and seems outdated and unmaitained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple [migration](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/migrations.html) that uses Craft's API to create entries programmatically. You can generate a new migration with the [`migrate/create` console command](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/console-commands.html#migrate-create):

```bash
php craft migrate/create content_import
```

This will create a new PHP file in the `migrations/` folder. You can put the migration code inside the `safeUp` method. To execute the migration:

```bash
php craft migrate/up
```

Inside the migration, you need access to your JSON. You can put the entire JSON string inside the migration, but I usually don't want to have that much data in my source control. Instead, I like to put the JSON inside the `migrations/` folder and load it inside the `safeUp` method:

```php
$json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . 'data.json');
$rows = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

This means you need to place this file in the production server manually, but that's fine since it's a one-time operation.

Once the JSON is loaded, you can create entries through the [`Elements` service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#method-saveelement):

```php
$contentSection = \Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle('myContentSection');
$contentEntryType = $contentSection->getEntryTypes()[0];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $entry = new \craft\elements\Entry();
    $entry->sectionId = $contentSection->Id;
    $entry->typeId = $contentEntryType->id;
    $entry->enabled = true;
    $entry->title = $row['title'];
    // Set more properties as needed, i.e. slug, postDate, etc.

    $entry->setFieldValues([
        'body' => $row['body'],
        // Set other custom fields
    ]);

    $success = \Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
    if (!$success) {
        \Craft::error('Couldn’t save the entry "' . $entry->title . '"', __METHOD__);
        return false;
    }
}
```

To test the migration repeatedly during migration, you need to modify the `safeDown` method. I like to put in code that deletes all the imported entries (careful, the following will delete all entries in the given section):

```php
$content = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
    ->section('myContentSection')
    ->status(null)
    ->all();

foreach ($content as $entry) {
    \Craft::$app->elements->deleteElement($entry, true);
}
```

Then you can redo the migration for testing purposes like this:

```bash
php craft migrate/redo 1
```

---

This may look complicated, but is pretty simple and quick once you've done it a few times. If this seems daunting, Feed Me is probably the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use FeedMe. It's excellent. If you don't need it again just remove it after you have used it.